# Modify .csproj in pre-build event

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, clickonce, csproj, pre-build-event

**tl;dr:** How to modify the `.csproj` file during publishing with `ClickOnce` while executing pre-build events?

***Long:***
I'm using TFS hosted by Microsoft for version control of my solution.

When publishing with `ClickOnce`, I get the latest revision number + 1 without problems. I also can successfully write the new version number into the `.csproj` file outside my build-process.

The problem is, that the `.csproj` file doesn't get updated during the build process - it might be in a write-lock. I get a notification inside Notepad++ about the modification of the file, but the file still contains the old version and VS didn't notice any changes.

The only solution by now I found to resolve this issue:
Move the revision update into the post-build events and add 2 instead of one to the actual revision number. Unfortunately this would cause that revision number would be out of date whenever other developers check-in code.

Comment: Updating the project file on the fly is a bad idea, you're probably better off creating a target file that updates the value of the variable at the right stage. Should you want to try what you're doing right now, turn off hosting for msbuild. http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/06/just-in-time-updating-of-source-files.html

Comment: @jessehouwing I agree with your idea. But wouldn't be any stage - no matter where I place it - cause changes on the .csproj file anyway? MsBuild reads the version number of the csproj file and not from e.g. the AssemblyInfo.cs when publishing with ClickOnce.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, strike that... :(.

After some more diffing, you'll need to override the GenerateApplicationManifest target to get this to work. That target doesn't use a `*DependsUpon` propertygroup, so it's harder to overwrite. The whole flow is defined in the `Microsoft.Common.Targets` file which you can find in the `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework{cpu}\{version} folder`.

See also:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a94df52-74c1-4fca-a830-ab530ec49207/use-msbuild-to-create-clickonce-app-files-in-alternate-location

Comment: Using the last part: `<ApplicationVersion>1.1.0.$(ApplicationRevision)`</ApplicationVersion> into your setup leads into a false output. Output is 0.0.2.246 instead of 1.1.0.254

Comment: After some more diffing, you'll need to override the `GenerateApplicationManifest` target to get this to work. That target doesn't use a "*DependsUpon" propertygroup, so it's harder to overwrite. The whole flow is defined in the Microsoft.Common.Targets file which you can find in the `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework{cpu}\{version}` folder.

Comment: Wow...i quickly scanned the `Microsoft.Common.Targets` file. This seems to be a huge task to modify it. And I won't be able to publish applications that don't run on a TFS, due to the broken behavior. I think modifying the build process to grab the TFS revision during the build process via a task is a bad idea.
What about letting the publish process "fail", if it's published with an outdated revision and force the developer to publish it again?

Comment: You don't have to modify the file, just re-declare the target in a file which is imported later (or at the bottom of your .csproj). The latest one wins.