# How to programmatically update project references in a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have a file structure like the following:

```
- binaries
   - binary1.dll
- dev
   - <developer-name>
      - a.csproj
-trunk
    - a.csproj
```

Developers who need to work on a.csproj will create a branch in dev and they will work from there. Our projects need to have a reference to binary1.dll in the binaries directory.

If the reference is a relative path (the Visual Studio default) then the path will not work both for the project in trunk and the project in the developer's branch.

To work around this problem I thought of creating an environment variable and using that in the project file instead:

```
<Reference Include="binary1">
   <HintPath>$(MY_ENV_VAR)\binary1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This works perfectly, but I wanted to help developers add references more easily, so I wrote a program that will convert relative paths that point to binary1.dll (for example, from the dev branch a.csproj it would change the path `../../binaries/binary1.dll` to `$(MY_ENV_VAR)\binary1.dll`) but I have not figured out how to get that to work.

If I use a pre-build event, the project is already loaded into memory and the event return an error because it cannot write the project file.

Then I realized that I could override MSBuild targets, and attempted with the targets: `BeforeCompiler`, `AfterCompiler`, `BeforeBuild`, `AfterBuild` and in all of them the project is already locked.

Then I ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726525/modify-csproj-in-pre-build-event) and I modified my code to call the executable in the `GenerateApplicationManifest` target, but that one doesn't seem to call the executable at all.

Some other ideas that I have been playing with are creating a new project that does the updating of the second project and have a link between them, but that would duplicate the number of projects.

I could also just change the depth of trunk, but that only hides the problem and doesn't really solve it. When developers create a branch inside their dev branch to work on different features or bugs then I have the same problem all over again.

There might also be another feature which fixes this in a more elegant way, but I haven't been able to find anything.

So my question: How do I get MS Build or pre-build events to modify a CS project?

Comment: for DLL you simply have to set a reference path in the project and change it to different folder to automatically use another version of the same dll

Comment: why not copy the dll with you when you branch?

Comment: @DLeh because I would end up with dozens of copies of my DLLs and updating a library to a new version would mean going through all the files in the SCC server and making sure that I changed all of them.

Comment: You could create an artificial folder under trunk :    trunk\ArtificialFolder
    - a.csproj         This would preserve your relative paths.

Comment: @granadaCoder In my question I do mention that I could solve it like that, but then if a developer creates a sub-branch we would have the same problem all over again. It is not a bad solution, but it is not ideal.

Comment: The "best" way to solve this is not to store dependencies in source-control.  But to use a binary-repository.  Nuget is the DotNet one....but I prefer the command line of "Ivy" (apache) for files.  http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html

Comment: @granadaCoder That is actually a pretty good solution as well, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. The issue was that the Visual Studio process itself was locking the project, but Visual Studio could overwrite the file. I ended up modifying a.csproj to include:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="UpdateReferences.exe" /> <!-- This creates the $(ProjectPath).new file -->
    <Move SourceFiles="$(ProjectPath).new" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectPath)" />
  </Target>
```